# No-except without passing argument

Tags: c++, c++11, noexcept

Can you say how can I assertion, is function noexcept(without passing arguments)? Thanks.

Comment: In general, you can't specify a function without also specifying arguments - there may be multiple overloads with the same name, some `noexcept` and others not.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you are asking (thanks to [@VittorioRomeo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41020740/4987285) for the assumption):

> How can I assert that a function is noexcept without calling it?

You can use the `noexcept` operator to do that, because its operands are unevaluated operands.
In other terms, you can do this:

```
void f(int) noexcept { }
void f(int, int) { }

int main() {
    static_assert(noexcept(f(0)), "!");
    static_assert(not noexcept(f(0, 0)), "!");
}
```

`f` won't be *called* in any case, that is the (let me say) *nature* of an unevaluated operand.

The most interesting part is that you can combine it with `std::declval` if you don't have a variable to be used as an argument and you don't know how to construct it.
As an example:

```
#include<utility>

struct S { S(int) {} };

void f(S) noexcept { }

int main() {
    static_assert(noexcept(f(std::declval<S>())), "!");
}
```

Note that I don't have to pass anything to construct `S`, even if it hasn't a default constructor.

This is usually enough to work around the requirement of *passing no arguments*.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're asking:

> How can I assert that a function is `noexcept` without calling it?

The answer is that you can't, because the `noexcept` specifier could be different between overloads. Example:

```
int a(int) noexcept;
int a(int, int);

// What would `noexcept(a)` mean?
```

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <string>

void ff()noexcept
{
}

class A
{
    public:
    void f()noexcept
    {
        ff();
    }
};

void g(A* obj,void (A::*f)())
{
    static_assert(noexcept((obj->*f)),"kl");
}

int main()
{
 A a;
 g(&a,&A::f);
}

Comment: For example I think that this returned wrong value


#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void ff()noexcept
{
}

class A
{
    public:
    void f()noexcept
    {
        ff();
    }
};

void g(A* obj,void (A::*f)())
{
    static_assert(noexcept((obj->*f)),"kl");
}

int main()
{
 A a;
 g(&a,&A::f);
}

Why it's asserted?

Comment: Can you please post that on wandbox or something similar?

Comment: @MartinAyvazyan Note the the noexcept specifier is not part of the function type in C++11. That's why your example _works_ even if you would have expected the opposite.

Comment: I have class( with as variadic template) and I need in other function check is this constexpr or no. What I should be done?

Comment: I have class( with as variadic template) and I need in other function check is this constexpr or no. What I should be done?

Comment: @MartinAyvazyan What are those types meant for? Are they member functions pointers or whatever?

Comment: They're member functions

Comment: If I want know is function, which's transferred as argument(pointer onto function), to have noexcept attribute or no, what I should be done?